# Finding the best working driver for a video card

Tags: drivers, graphics

where can I look for the best working driver for a video card (and if available at all)?

In my case it is a "Nvidia Geforce GTX 580", because I've read that the drivers are better for Nvida than for ATI video cards. When I try to run Minecraft with my current ATI video card, the game crashes. (It's a well known case and it's something with the ATI driver.) Most games run fine though.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The best driver for what you are doing will be the proprietary one from Nvidia, so you go to their site: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
There is no comprehensive site for all cards/drivers and the open source drivers except this forum so you have come to the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the nVidia driver with GLX. Depending on your distribution, it is probably packaged either as `nvidia-glx-new`, `nvidia-glx` (note: on Ubuntu, out of the two you probably want `nvidia-glx-new`) or `nvidia`. Bear in mind that this driver is proprietary software.

Comment: Thanks, but my main question is how to find them? Is there a site where you enter the name of the video card and get information about the best driver (if available), what it supports, how to install it and how stable and fast it is?

Comment: @Joschua The wiki for your distribution is usually a good choice.